# Webpack 5 node modules css file: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I wrote an web app with React (frontend) and Node (backend). To improve SEO, I implemented Reacht 18 SSR while also adding Webpack and Babel in the backend to create a server.bundle.js that can be used to pre-render React.

Unfortunately I get the following error when I run npm start in the root directory

**Error message**

```
server@0.1.0 prestart
webpack --config webpack.config.js
webpack 5.88.1 compiled successfully in 11395 ms
server@0.1.0 start
node build/server.bundle.js
D:\Daten E\Sao\server\node_modules\rc-slider\assets\index.css:1
.rc-slider {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at 3130 (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:452050)
    at r (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:1242918)
    at 1205 (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:502608)
    at r (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:1242918)
    at 2156 (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:519155)
    at r (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:1242918)
    at 4430 (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:472108)
    at r (D:\Daten E\Sao\server\build\server.bundle.js:2:1242918)
Node.js v18.13.0
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: 'server.bundle.js',
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ],
  };
};
```

I have already looked for solutions. The suggestion to add the package babel-plugin-css-modules-transform (https://medium.com/react-ssr-server-side-rendering-webpack-configurat/how-to-fix-issue-1-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-loading-css-eecaccfcb57e) unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Can someone please tell me why the error comes and what to do?